# Changing CSS if my h3 does't appear first on the page (PHP CSS or JS)

Tags: javascript, php, css, if-statement

I'm working in a bespoke CMS for a client and I want to apply different CSS to the first p tag if my h3 doesn't appear before it.

It seems like the solution would be something like - "if h3 doesn't apear first add 20px margin-top to first p tag" or something. I'm just not sure how to write this in php or js.

my page looks like this normally.

h1
h2
h3
p

but occasionally my page doesn't have a h3 which causes the p to sit too close to the h2.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: anywhere before it thanks

Comment: p { margin-top: 20px;} h3+p{ margin-top: 0; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>next demo</title>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<h1>Heading h1</h1>
<h2>Heading h2</h2>
<p>p tag will change if h3 is not found</p>

  <p>Shouldn't affect this</p>
  
 
<script>
$( "h2" ).next( "p" ).css({"margin-top":"20px", "font-size":"25px" });
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>next demo</title>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
     
    <h1>Heading h1</h1>
    <h2>Heading h2</h2>
    <h3>Heading h3</h3>
    <p>p tag will not change if h3 is found</p>

      <p>Shouldn't affect this</p>
      
     
    <script>
    $( "h2" ).next( "p" ).css({"margin-top":"20px", "font-size":"25px" });
    </script>
     
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Big Bla</h1>
<h2>Medium Bla</h2>
<h3 style="min-height:20px;">Small Bla</h3>
```

If you don't want to show h3, keep the tag on the document, just hide the contents